# Angular: Concatenate formArray ngfor index inside string in reactive forms

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form which holds a form array which holds a formGroup and inside it a form controls

```
this.questionsForm = new FormGroup({
      'theWholeForm':new FormArray([
        new FormGroup({
          "question": new FormControl(null) ,
          "questionType":new FormControl('True or False') 
        })
      ]),
      
    });

getTheWholeForm(){
    return (this.questionsForm.get('theWholeForm') as FormArray).controls;
  }
```

so in order to access the formcontrols, This works fine because the name of the form group is the number of index,

```
this.questionsForm.get('theWholeForm.0.questionType')!.value
```

So how to access it from the html
in html:

```
<form [formGroup]="questionsForm" (ngSubmit)="onNext()" class=" ">
        <div formArrayName="theWholeForm">
            <div *ngFor="let qt of getTheWholeForm();let r = index">
              {{this.questionsForm.get('theWholeForm.r.questionType')!.value}} 
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

But it gives me an error

> [Can't read property 'value' of null]

I think this is actually becuase it reads 'r' as the the actual name of the formgroup and not the index.

How can I solve this ? or how can I till angular that this 'r' is the variable r which holds the index and not a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the string concatenation to insert the index in the parameter of the `get()` method?

I think this is the problem. Angular handles `('theWholeForm.r.questionType')` as a string.

So, it will not resolve the `r` as the index of the `*ngFor=""`.

I think it will be solved if you tried `('theWholeForm.' + r + '.questionType')`

Comment: Ohh wow ,this was a stupid question , thanks man it worked fine, I didn't think of it like a normal concatenation, I was thinking of something like {{r}} or ${r} . thank you

Answer (score 0):

Declare a getter in your TS file and use this in your template

```typescript
  get theWholeForm() {
    return this.questionsForm.get('theWholeForm') as FormArray;
  }
```

and in your html

```html
     <div *ngFor="let qt of getTheWholeForm();let r = index">
       {{ theWholeForm.controls[r].get('questionType').value}} 
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like following:

```
<form [formGroup]="questionsForm" (ngSubmit)="onNext()" class=" ">
        <div formArrayName="theWholeForm">
            <div *ngFor="let qt of getTheWholeForm();let r = index">
              {{ qt.get('questionType')!.value }} 
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```